# Linear Algebra, Image & Kernel

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having difficulty in proving the following. Any assistance would be appreciated. 
Let $\sigma_{0}\neq\alpha\in $End($\mathbb{C}^{3})$ such that $\alpha^{2}=\sigma_{0}$. Show that im($\alpha)\subseteq $ ker$(\alpha)$. Note that $\sigma_{0}$ is the identity element for addition.

Comment: So $\sigma_0$ is simply the zero map?

Comment: Yes. We have $\sigma_{0}:v  \mapsto 0_{V}$. (Sorry for delayed response: virus problem with my PC.)

Answer (score 1):

In general, given $\textsf{T}:\textsf{V}\to\textsf{V}$ a linear transformation that satisfies $\textsf{T}\circ \textsf{T}=\textsf{T}_0$, where $\textsf{T}_0$ is the zero map, we have that $\operatorname{im}(\textsf{T})\subseteq \ker(\textsf{T})$. And here is a short proof:

Let $y\in \operatorname{im}(\textsf{T})$, then $y=\textsf{T}(x)$ for some $x\in \textsf{V}$. Since
$$\textsf{T}(y)=\textsf{T}(\textsf{T}(x))=\textsf{T}_0(x)=0_\textsf{V}$$
we have $y\in \ker(\textsf{T})$. That is, every vector living in $\operatorname{im}(\textsf{T})$ is also in $\ker(\textsf{T})$, thus $\operatorname{im}(\textsf{T})\subseteq \ker(\textsf{T})$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $v = \alpha(w) \in \text{im}(\alpha)$. Then we can apply $\alpha$ to both sides and get
$$\alpha(v) = \alpha^2(w) = \sigma_0(w) = 0,$$ such that $v \in \text{ker}(\alpha)$. Thus we have $\text{im}(\alpha) \subset \text{ker}(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Take $v\in\operatorname{im}(\alpha)$. You want to prove that $v\in\ker\alpha$. Asserting that $v\in\operatorname{im}(\alpha)$ means that $v=\alpha(u)$ for some vector $u$ and asserting that $v\in\ker\alpha$ means that $\alpha(v)=0$. So…